# ios safari won't display font-face embedded fonts in svg files. any fix?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, svg, font-face

So I have a SVG file, that contains text elements. Example:

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 195.248 207.165)" fill="#999999" font-family="'LeagueGothic'" font-size="24">Europe</text>
```

When I specify the font-family to something included in iOS (like Helvetica or Futura), everything works fine. However, once I specify a font included through @font-face, it simply doesn't work on iOS, while it does on desktop Safari, Chrome, Firefox as well as Opera.

Otherwise @font-face fonts work ok throughout the page, except the SVG parts.

Tried including the SVG file as `<embed>`, `<object>` and `<img>`, didn't help. Interestingly, when I try inline SVG (i.e. SVG code directly within HTML), then the fonts are ok, but it doesn't draw anything else form the SVG file.

I am on iOS 4.2. Tried SVG 1.1, 1.1 Tiny, 1.2, etc. all the same.

Is this a bug or am I missing something, please? Thanks.

Sample SVG file here: http://pastie.org/1637291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your svg sample has no @font-face rule, nor references to any external stylesheets. Maybe a solution could be to include a stylesheet with that definition in the svg file itself.

For example:

```
<style>
@font-face { font-family: foo; src: url(somefont.svg#theFontElementId) format("svg"); }
</style>
```

If you are referencing the svg parts with e.g `<object>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>` or `<img>` and see the webfont elsewhere on the page then that missing stylesheet thing could be the cause.

Comment: Wow, this really works. Thanks a lot! The @font-face definition was included in a css file that was linked in the same html page as my svg file. So all fonts appeared ok (@font-faced), except those in svg. So repeating the @font-face definition directly in the svg file worked. Btw. it doesn't have to be a svg font, I have ttf and otf and it works.

Comment: Oh WOW. _Now_ I'm *really* impressed. I had no idea you could place so much stuff inside an SVG and it would still work. I was embedding a very simple logo — just some text in a fancy font face and a few squares — and was getting really frustrated with the thought that I would have to convert the whole text to SVG paths, making it huge (it has about 1KB otherwise). In my case, I'm embedding a `woff2` font but _also_ checking first if the font is locally installed (speeds up the process!). Thanks!